# Install docker desktop but when I run docker command it gives the error: exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to run docker desktop on my ubuntu-22.04 but when I run any docker command in the terminal it gives the following error:

```
exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in $PATH
Current PATH : /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/
```

I noticed that my com.docker.cli file is colored red in the folder: usr/local/bin see my image:

[image]

I also noticed that there is no docker directory in /usr/bin

[image]
Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
ls -ld /usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli
```

will likely reveal that the file `/usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli` is an invalid symbolic link. That means that the executable file to which it refers is not any longer existing. It may have been moved or deleted.

If the executable file simply has been moved, you would be able to repair this by deleting the symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli` and recreating it so it points to the correct executable, as in

```
ln -s `/<true/path/to/executable>` /usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli
```

Else, your docker installation may have been more seriously damaged, and then you may need to reinstall the application.

Comment: I ran the command you said and the result was:
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Aug 26 21:14 ./com.docker.cli -> /usr/bin/docker`

The problem I install and uninstall but it doesn't create the docker file in `/usr/bin/docker`

Comment: Might be installed elsewhere, e.g. under `/usr/local/bin`, but then it is strange that the link is in `/usr/bin`

Comment: I installed the docker engine and pulled the docker executable from the docker binary

Comment: @RafaelSouza I'm having the exact same problem. Can you please explain how you did the above?

Comment: try to download the docker executable from the binary repository and put it in the usr/bin directory if you don't have any docker file @karjedavpalaa

Answer (score 1):

i used the below command after i got the same error.

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

now working perfectly fine

This command is usually used to fix all the broken packages or reinstall from the official repo

Answer (score -2):

On Debian I had the exact same error after a manual binary installation.

Even if my binary was inside the `/usr/bin` which was already in the PATH, it still was not working. Running `/usr/bin/docker` was working though.

It turned out that I had the binary in both `/usr/bin/docker` and `/usr/local/bin/docker`.

I had to have instead a symlink between these 2 paths, rather than 2 independent binaries.

So I removed the `/usr/local/bin/docker` file and added instead a symlink from the `/usr/bin/docker`

```
ln -s /usr/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/docker
```

Comment: `PATH` should contain directories, unless `/usr/bin/docker` is a directory, this is not what solved your problem even if it appeared to do so (check everything else you tried before this).

Comment: @muru you were right. I looked back and what did the track was adding the symlink 
`ln -s /usr/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/docker`

I modified my post.

Comment: If you had a faulty file in `/usr/local/bin`, removing it should have been sufficient. Adding another symlink would be unnecessary (though I would investigate how that broken file came to be there in the first place)